# It is necessary to send alerts to Telegram bot from Teams using webhook_url

Tags: c++, microsoft-teams, telegram-bot

The program will hang on the server and work around the clock. It is necessary to catch the received message in the Microsoft-Teams group (channel) via webhook_url and send at least one message (preferably a whole message) to the bot's Telegram. I write code on the pluses as I don’t know anything other than them. Below is the code. The code did not work for me, if there are any ideas or suggestions on how to improve what I am certainly happy about. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h> // Library for working with HTTP requests
using namespace std;

// Incoming webhook URL created in Teams
const string webhook_url = "Webhook from Tims";

// Telegram bot access token
const string bot_token = "Bot token";

// Telegram chat ID where to send notifications
const string chat_id = "Bot name";

size_t write_callback(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userdata) {
    // The callback function used to store the server's response
    string* response = (string*)userdata;
    response->append((char*)ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

void send_webhook_message(const string& text, const string& bot_token, const string& chat_id) {
    // Function for sending a webhook message through a bot in Telegram
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        string response;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, ("https://t.me/ITSys****" + bot_token + "/sendMessage").c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ("chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + text).c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
        curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
int main ()
{for ( ; ; )
{
    
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's your web server that receives the webhook request?

Comment: Teams has a built-in webhook app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook

Comment: Yep (though that's for incoming messages, not outgoing messages which doesn't seem to be what you want?) but how does your code work with it? You've just got an infinite loop in `main` your code doesn't actually do anything

Comment: Yes main doesn’t work now, but I want to fix it. Function main just not ended. Are u right that webhook wok on incoming message in a group and my target is to get this message with this webhook and notify in telegram automatically. I’m so sorry for my English he is bad.

Comment: you need an [outgoing webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=urljsonpayload%2Cdotnet) or a [bot](https://dev.botframework.com/)

Comment: ty i will try to do with wthat method